# Can I define a specific class type in a class that implements an interface with a generic type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, inheritance

I have this interface and class that implements it below. It initially had data as a 'IYogaEvent[]' and now I want to use it for multiple items, so I created a generic to pass in.

Can I use a specific value other than 'any' as the data property type?
I want to be able to use either 'IYogaEvent[]' or 'IUser[]' but can only figure out how to give data a type of 'any'

```js
export interface IPagination <T> {
  pageIndex: number;
  pageSize: number;
  count: number;
  data: T;
  // data: IYogaEvent[];
  // data: IUser[];
}

export class Pagination implements IPagination <any> {
  pageIndex: number;
  pageSize: number;
  count: number;
  data: any;
  // data: IYogaEvent[] = [];
  // data: IUser[] = [];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do the same thing and forward the generic type:

```
export interface IPagination<T> {
  pageIndex: number;
  pageSize: number;
  count: number;
  data: T;
}

export class Pagination<T> implements IPagination<T> {
  pageIndex: number;
  pageSize: number;
  count: number;
  data: T;
}
```

Comment: thanks! I was missing the <T> on the class Pagination

Comment: If you think this was a silly question I can delete it

Comment: "There's no such thing as a stupid question" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_such_thing_as_a_stupid_question :)

Comment: Oh sorry I am not native english speaker ^^